# How do I build and run an existing project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to start the program from this repository: https://github.com/SaifurRahmanMohsin/Personal-Diary but when I dowload it and open the project in Eclipse I am not able to build/compile it. So i also can't run it.

Do I have to change run configurations or build a working set or something like that? I usually don't work with Eclipse so I am a bit overwhelmed.

[screenshot eclipse1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzeHv.png)

[screenshot eclipse2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ip3O.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check out. Delete the files `.project`, `.classpath`, and folder `.settings`  before you import because those hold data unrelated to your system.

File, Import, Project from existing sources

Pick the inner `Personal Diary` folder, not the repo folder

You will need to download two libraries to add to the classpath

JSON-Simple and Apache HTTP Client

Comment: the output is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tempestronics.Launcher and that's becuase it isn't compiled, is it?

Comment: Right. I would suggest deleting the `.project`, `.classpath`, and `.settings` files before you import